# Error: Unable to resolve module `react-redux` from `C:\Users\wanuuu27\AwesomeProject\App.js`: Module `react-redux` does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import "tachyons"
import FormContainer from './modules/form/form.container';
import configureStore from './modules/store';

const store = configureStore();

import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
    ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
            'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
    android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
            'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
            <FormContainer />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed `react-redux` on your project yet?  Does your `package.json` file list it under the dependencies?  If your `package.json` lists all of these dependencies, then you'll want to run (from the command line, in the project directly) `npm install`.

If your `package.json` does not have `react-redux` and you're trying to add it to your project, then (from the command line, in the project directory) run `npm install react-redux --save`.  That command will both add `react-redux` to your `package.json` AND install the `react-redux` package into your `node_modules` folder.